# How do you reference using apa style in latex?

Tags: cross-referencing, apa-style, back-referencing, apa6

I googled and searched alot or maybe i'm just missing something i dont know.. My problem is i want to do a reference page using apa style. I kept on trying but doesn't seem to give any output.. Anyone mind to help me? :(

Here's my current code :

In main.tex

```
\usepackage{apacite}
```

In reference.tex

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{References}
```

In References.bib

```
@online{What Is Autism?,
    title = {What Is Autism?},
    date = {n.d.},
    url = {https://www.autismspeaks.org/what-autism},
}
```

My screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\bibliographystyle{apalike}` should provide the output you wish, if you in your case `\cite{online}`.

I don't think `apacite` is a standard package for bibliographystyle?

Are your bibtex items properly written out in a .bib file, and imported to your main .tex?

Look at [this resource](http://sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles) they provide a nice overview.

Comment: sorry.. i put wrongly.. i used the \usepackage{apacite} in main.tex and \bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{References} in reference.tex
 and @online{What Is Autism?,
 title = {What Is Autism?},
 date = {n.d.},
 url = {https://www.autismspeaks.org/what-autism},
} in References.bib but i dont get the output.. :(

Comment: What is your output? Is an error provided, or does it not show up at all? Maybe take a screenshot and post it if you're unsure.

Comment: it doesn't show anything at all.. i've included the screenshot in my question..

Comment: if you try to use the `apalike` package, we could see if it's the package you call for that's the problem or the syntax itself. If the same error happens, it's something outside of the dependencies which provides the issue. If `apalike` works, it means the issue lies within your `apacite` package.

Comment: i changed to apacite package also didnt work..

Comment: Okay, so it's the syntax. Delete the Largebf text you have got going, References should occur by itself, no need to call it. Remove that. What happens when you compile then? Also, do you compile properly? Compile the latex file, then compile bibtex - then compile latex twice after.

Comment: i deleted Largebf.. the "reference" disappeared..  i just press build & view.. i'm using TeXstudio..

Comment: oh no wait the "reference" title is there but just that my bib not coming out.. and it became "bibliography " instead of reference..

Comment: What happens if you move `bibliographystyle` to the beginning of your main document and `bibliography` to the end of it, assuming of course you want the references in the end?

Comment: still the same... only the bibliography title and empty..

Comment: Okay, how do you `cite` it? Some packages won't allow your references. Maybe rename it to `autism` instead of What is Autism? and try to `\cite{autism}` - what's the output?

Comment: i didnt use cite.. i actually written myself.. like (what is autism?, n.d.).. i changed to autism.. not coming out..

Comment: Then what do you use to reference? Unless you call it with i.e. `\cite{ref}` or `\citep{ref}` the reference itself won't be produced even though it's present in the bibtex library.